# How i can change date format in vue.js

Tags: date, vue.js

How i can change date format to be like this : 26-october 22:01:12

Running with Laravel and vue.js

I expect the output 2019-03-26 08:29:23

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for that purpose.

```
import moment from 'moment'

moment('2019-03-26 08:29:23').format('DD-MMMM HH:mm:ss') // outputs 26-March 08:29:23
```